# Firebase not retrieving data (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have been messing around with Firebase for the first time in iOS. I have succesfully written data to the firebase and have organized it like so:

```
{
"users" : {
"6ytX7ZLa28MYXX8zm3gawJiOYuY2" : {
  "-Kmj196aXH9uRXd-bCgB" : {
    "category" : "Work",
    "date" : "Jun 16, 1:54 AM ",
    "place" : "Tampa, Forida",
    "title" : "make an app"
  },
  "-Kmj1HcNcDb9gD2TTlQB" : {
    "category" : "Design",
    "date" : "Jun 18, 12:58 AM ",
    "place" : "Sarasota",
    "title" : "Design an app"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I currently have the following code to try to retrieve the data, but it is rendering unsuccessful. Any help that you could provide would be very much appreciated!

**TableViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class TasksHome: UITableViewController {

private var databaseHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var user: FIRUser!
var username: String!
var items = [Item]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    username = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    startObservingDatabase()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TasksHomeCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = item.title
    cell.categoryLabel.text = item.category
    cell.placeLabel.text = item.place
    cell.dateLabel.text = item.date

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        item.ref?.removeValue()
    }
}


func startObservingDatabase () {
   databaseHandle = ref?.child("users").child(self.username).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let category = userDict["category"] as! String
        let date = userDict["date"] as! String
        let title = userDict["title"] as! String
        let place = userDict["place"] as! String
        print("category: \(category)  date: \(date) title: \(title) place: \(place)")
    })
}

deinit {
    ref.child("users/\(self.user.uid)/items").removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
}

}
```

**Item File**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

class Item {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
var title: String?
var category: String?
var date: String?
var place: String?

init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    ref = snapshot.ref

    let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
    title = data["title"]! as String
    category = data["category"]! as String
    date = data["date"]! as String
    place = data["place"]! as String
}

}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: 1: Any errors thrown? If yes, can you add them to your question. 2: Is the print statement inside `startObservingDatabase()` called?

Comment: Hello, Eshirima! No errors are thrown when run, and the print statement is not called. When called elsewhere, it returns nil for all constituents.

Comment: What do u mean by _When called elsewhere, it returns nil for all constituents_? Also you need to iterate through `snapshot` to obtain its contents since it consists of other dictionaries. Its a dictionary of dictionaries. Comment out everything inside the completion handler and simply write `print(snapshot)` to se what it looks like

Comment: When I add: 'print(snapshot)' in the completion handler nothing prints. I have checked to make sure my .plist from firebase is correct with the corresponding database URL and such.

Comment: What about your child paths and stuff? I saw that you're iterating over users/username. Is that correct? Also try making it a observeSingleEvent. It might be an issue with the observance.

Comment: It seems your user objects are nested too far into the array and there's an extra child. You ideally should have the "users" array in the database and have an array of children as the user objects. But those children are children of the "6ytX7ZLa28MYXX8zm3gawJiOYuY2" string, I'm not sure why that's there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the optional value returned by your uid is causing you not to get values back or your database rules. Try the following solution where I have ensured there are no optionals and I have used the cancel block to check if there was a problem making the query to Firebase. It's a modification to your viewDidLoad, do not call your startObservingDatabase method with this though. If you get "could not find user" then the problem might be with your authentication. If you get "error observing value ..." then the problem might be with your database security validation rules, try make them all public if they are not already and see if you get anything back. If you get none of these but you now get a value back with this solution then the problem might be with the optionals in your firebase reference.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
       userId = user.uid
       let baseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
       databaseHandle = baseRef.child("users").child(userId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
    print("we got a value \(snapshot)")
    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let category = userDict["category"] as! String
    let date = userDict["date"] as! String
    let title = userDict["title"] as! String
    let place = userDict["place"] as! String
    print("category: \(category)  date: \(date) title: \(title) place: \(place)")
}, withCancel: { (error) in
            print("error observing value \(error)")
        })

    }
    else {
        print("could not find user")
    }

 }
```